# GNOME application doesn't use the system input method

Tags: 11.10, gnome, input-method, chinese

I set my system input method to `gcin` with `im-switcher`.

But when I use some GNOME based application, such as `gedit` and `gnome-terminal`, my default input method is still `Simple`(i.e. I can type only English letter).

But in other applications, like `Chrome`, I can use `gcin` and everything works well.

Why does GNOME have a different input method setting? And how can I change it?

Comment: I'm using ubuntu 11.10

Answer (score 3):

You need to enable IBus and select the method of input. Restart X-server or reboot.

Right click on the applications when opened ie: Gedit, to change input method.

Let me attach the windows options you should have:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Now I can select input method in context menu. But how to set it as default?