# Input methods missing in gnome-terminal context menu

Tags: 14.04, gnome-terminal, input-method

On ubuntu 14.04. For gnome-terminal, I right click in the terminal window I get the context men but without Input Methods. What should I do to have it there?

Comment: It may be that you need to restart bewteen activating ibus, and using input methods in gnome - does that make sense for your situation? Can you try?

Comment: This question was fully messed up at the start, with no real title - but after editing, it's actually a very valid and useful question, it seems.

Comment: If that does not help, you will need to add details: what works, what not what did you try, why do you expect that the menu should be there?

Comment: Related http://askubuntu.com/questions/106586/gnome-application-doesnt-use-the-system-input-method/106652

Answer (score 0):

14.04 uses `gnome-terminal 3.6.2`. As of Gnome 3.6, Gnome uses Ibus as the only input method by default; so the context menu (right-click popup) to change the input method is no longer applicable and has been removed.

For more information, see [Integrated Input Methods](https://help.gnome.org/misc/release-notes/3.6/i18n-ibus.html.en) and [How to Use Other IM Frameworks](https://wiki.gnome.org/ThreePointFive/Features/IBus#How_to_use_other_IM_frameworks) .

These pages, however, talk about turning Gnome integration with Ibus on and off, but it's still a system-wide setting. It will allow you to use other IM methods, but it won't bring the context menu back.